# How do you query in SQLite3 with foreign keys and different tables?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I am trying to query certain things like retrieving the movie name based on the director name of "Ang Lee".  I have Movie and Director seperated into two tables.  I have a third table that has the movie ID and director ID, that I am trying to tie everything toegether with.  So one thing I need to do would be find the movies (MId, Title, ReleaseDate) directed by name 'Ang Lee'.  What type of query do I have to send in order to get this result?  Here is a background of my code:

```
CREATE TABLE MOVIE(
    MId INTEGER,
    Title VARCHAR(50),
    ReleaseDate DATE,
    Budget DOUBLE,
    PRIMARY KEY (MId)
);


CREATE TABLE DIRECTOR(
    DId INTEGER,
    Name VARCHAR(30),
    DateOfBirth DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (DId)
);

CREATE TABLE DIRECTED(
    DirectorId INTEGER,
    MovieId INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(DirectorId, MovieId),
    FOREIGN KEY(DirectorId) REFERENCES DIRECTOR(DId),
    FOREIGN KEY(MovieId) REFERENCES MOVIE(MId)
);

INSERT INTO MOVIE VALUES(1, 'Life of Pi', '2012-11-21', 120000000);
INSERT INTO MOVIE VALUES(3, 'Argo', '2012-10-12', 44500000);
INSERT INTO MOVIE VALUES(7, 'The Dark Knight Rises', '2012-07-20', 250000000);
INSERT INTO MOVIE VALUES(15, 'Thor', '2011-12-10', 150000000);
INSERT INTO MOVIE VALUES(45, 'The Sessions', '2012-01-23', 1000000);
INSERT INTO MOVIE VALUES(65, 'Batman Begins', '2005-06-15', 150000000);
INSERT INTO MOVIE VALUES(86, 'Goodfellas', '1990-09-19', 25000000);
INSERT INTO MOVIE VALUES(95, 'The Departed', '2006-10-06', 90000000);
INSERT INTO MOVIE VALUES(103, 'There's Something about Mary', '1998-07-15', 23000000);
INSERT INTO MOVIE VALUES(123, 'The Matrix', '1999-05-31', 63000000);
INSERT INTO MOVIE VALUES(144, 'Lust, Caution', '2007-09-28', 15000000);

INSERT INTO DIRECTOR VALUES(4, 'Ang Lee', '1954-10-23');
INSERT INTO DIRECTOR VALUES(5, 'Ben Affleck', '1972-08-15');
INSERT INTO DIRECTOR VALUES(8, 'Christopher Nolan', '1970-07-30');
INSERT INTO DIRECTOR VALUES(9, 'Kenneth Branagh', '1960-12-10');
INSERT INTO DIRECTOR VALUES(13, 'Ben Lewin', '1946-01-23');
INSERT INTO DIRECTOR VALUES(23, 'Martin Scorsese', '1942-11-17');
INSERT INTO DIRECTOR VALUES(25, 'Christopher Nolan', '1970-07-30');
INSERT INTO DIRECTOR VALUES(33, 'Peter Farrelly', '1956-12-17');
INSERT INTO DIRECTOR VALUES(34, 'Robert Farrelly', '1958-06-17');
INSERT INTO DIRECTOR VALUES(45, 'Lana Wachowski', '1965,06-21');
INSERT INTO DIRECTOR VALUES(46, 'Andrew Wachowski', '1967-12-29');

INSERT INTO DIRECTED VALUES(4, 1);
INSERT INTO DIRECTED VALUES(5, 3);
INSERT INTO DIRECTED VALUES(8, 7);
INSERT INTO DIRECTED VALUES(9, 15);
INSERT INTO DIRECTED VALUES(13, 45);
INSERT INTO DIRECTED VALUES(25, 65);
INSERT INTO DIRECTED VALUES(23, 86);
INSERT INTO DIRECTED VALUES(23, 95);
INSERT INTO DIRECTED VALUES(33, 103);
INSERT INTO DIRECTED VALUES(34, 103);
INSERT INTO DIRECTED VALUES(45, 123);
INSERT INTO DIRECTED VALUES(46, 123);
INSERT INTO DIRECTED VALUES(4, 144);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT m.MId, m.Title, m.ReleaseDate   
FROM DIRECTED dir, DIRECTOR d, MOVIE m WHERE
d.Name = 'Ang Lee' AND
d.DId = dir.DirectorId AND
dir.MovieId = m.MId
```

Take a look at the [concept of joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

Comment: This seems to work for the most part.  When I query this, it only pulled up one of the movies which is "Life of Pi".  How would I also get "Lust, Caution"?

Comment: You can use it. Simply replace ' by '' (so two times '). Basically you can use arbitrary names. The only thing you have to do is to escape them in your SQL query. Check this out: http://www.kamath.com/codelibrary/cl003_apostrophe.asp